# Opening file manager using xdg-open gives warnings (nemo:85552): Gtk-WARNING **

Tags: gtk, linux-mint, xdgutils

I am new to using linux mint. Used "xdg-open ." to open the current directory in the file manager. But when I do this I get the following warnings.

> *(nemo:85552): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:21:45.991: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable
> to register client Nemo-Share-Message: 09:21:46.385: Called "net
> usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net
> usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares.
> Error No such file or directory Please ask your system administrator
> to enable user sharing.*

And upon closing the file manager window I get

> (nemo:85552): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:21:47.482: gtk_widget_destroy:
> assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Is there a way I can fix this ?

Thank you.